# pip: need to change name of package tensorflow-gpu to tensorflow

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow with gpu support into a conda environment

I use the command:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

When I look at the packages installed with conda list I wind up with a package called tensorflow-gpu.

You cannot even import this package because it has a '-' in it.

How can I change the name to 'tensorflow'?

Edit:  I'm now thinking that there must be something more to this.  Why would a major package in the deep learning community have this apparent problem.  Hopefully, a tensorflow expert can answer.  I'm following the directions for Ubuntu and Anaconda here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Comment: I assume it might not be possible with `pip`

Comment: A possible "hack" until you figure this out is to [import the module as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path), and then reassign it to a valid Python name,  such as `tensorflow_gpu`.

Comment: Problem is other packages I import are also trying to import 'tensorflow' and fail.  Is there a pip command to change the name?

Comment: Would using the string hack satisfy other packages that import tensorflow?

Comment: It seems pretty silly to have this problem. I'm following the instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package

Comment: the actual package is called "tensorflow", tensorflow-gpu and tensorflow both install the same package as far as pip is concerned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install the tensorflow gpu version, Anaconda will show that you have installed tensorflow-gpu.  The -gpu just indicates that it is a gpu version and is not a part of the name.  You can still just import tensorflow and the gpu version will be found.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was quite frustrating.  I started with recently built .whl file and tried to install.

```
pip install /home/ubuntu/xfer/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Command line testing:

```
pip show tensorflow
```

*no package called tensorflow*

```
pip show tensorflow-gpu
```

*but there is a package tensorflow-gpu at version 1.2.1*

However, running one line in python failed despite assurances that conda would substitute:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I then repeated the pip install of the .whl file with the --upgrade option:

```
pip install --upgrade /home/ubuntu/xfer/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

And then the one line of python succeeded:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

And in fact based on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#run_a_short_tensorflow_program, one would then run a slightly longer program which also succeeds:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```